# jquery stopPropagation(); not working with anchor

Tags: jquery

There is a click event assigned to the parent `tr` class name `type-shop_order`.
When clicking a child element checkbox this successfully stops the parent click event from firing.

When clicking a child element anchor tag, the `type-shop_order` click event still fires.

```
$(".type-shop_order .shop_order_single_table input[type='checkbox']").on("click", function(e) { 
   e.stopPropagation();
});         

$(".type-shop_order .shop_order_single_table a").on("click", function(e) { 
   e.stopPropagation();
});
```

How do i solve?  The first works but the second doesn't.

The parent click event is `slideDown` for a child div in a table cell.

The anchors are added dynamically with jquery btw.

Comment: There is no reason for it to not work... Can we know a bit more about the event you are trying to prevent from occurring? And what "does not work" mean exactly? what does it do when it does not work?

Comment: Can you post a complete code example including the HTML?

Comment: see edit.  The anchors are added dynamically btw.

Comment: @user892134 "The anchors are added dynamically btw." Well, that's your problem; look up one of the many, many questions and answers on event delegation here on SO.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Event binding on dynamically created elements?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/203198/event-binding-on-dynamically-created-elements)